# How to allow several different origins in Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, cors, wildfly

My goal is to allow several **BUT NOT ALL** origins for http requests to my Wildfly 10. I have searched StackOverflow and haven't found anything so far on this topic. People all over the Internet suggest using a wildcard, however this could effectively be a security flaw. Yes, a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` does work, but I don't want to allow just any origin. I have tried this `standalone.xml` part for `undertow` subsystem  (unsuccessfully):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="314572800" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header1"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header2"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header3"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header1" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://122.22.22.24:*"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header2" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://122.22.22.21:*"/>  
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header3" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://122.22.22.22:*"/>      
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods-header" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers-header" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials-header" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age-header" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This nice [article](https://medium.com/amritatech/a-mechanism-to-enable-cors-filter-with-no-coding-57ef2906e023) is explaining one way to do it, using an Undertow `expression-filter` validating origin against some whitelisted domains (modelled as a multi-valued|-separated list):

```
<property name=”cors.whitelist” value=”http://domainA|http://domainB"/>
```

All credits go to the article author :-)